# iOS development on windows without any apple device?

Tags: ios, development

I want to do some cross-platform mobile development (Android, iOS, Windows Phone) using Xamarin, the problem is that I only have an android device and a windows machine. But I still want to be able to test my apps for iOS and I can't really buy a mac (and/or an iphone) just for this. I'm thinking about testing my apps using Appetize.io, but to do that I would still need a MAC machine to be able to build the app and upload to appetize. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Really you might find a hack but you might also spend so much time and effort as it would be cheaper to buy a used iPhone and/or Mac. Besides your question is about Software development, which is Officially Off-Topic for this site. You should delete this and move it to https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @SteveChambers only programming questions are considered off-topic, questions about dev environments are welcome on AD. The first part of your comment is spot on, though :-)

Comment: Cool, thanx for the info...

Answer (score 2):

You need Xcode to build, sign and upload your app; it also is advisable to test it on real hardware (aka an iPhone) before releasing it. Xcode is only available for macOS though so you need at least a small Mac mini for this (which is more than enough for smaller apps)

Comment: I know that, I ask if there is any workaround for this, like not deploy the app, but just be able to test it for example on appetize. I'm not working on any commercial app or anything like that, I'm just starting to learn cross platform mobile development (coming from android development). I can not afford to buy another device right now specially that I do not have any project from which I'll make money to cover my costs.

Comment: @RobertNisipeanu You need Xcode, there is no way around that.